# disable button Problem in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a form that trigger onsubmit a java script function like the following

```
<form:form commandName="achievment" method="post" id="achievmentForm"  enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="disableButtons(this);" cssClass="validatable">

<input id="button1" type="submit" class="button" name="add" onclick="bCancel=false" value="إضافة" />

</form:form>
```

and the js code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function disableButtons(form){
 if(jQuery(form).valid()){
  jQuery('input:button').removeClass('button');
  jQuery('input:button').addClass('grayButton');
  jQuery('input:submit').removeClass('button');
  jQuery('input:submit').addClass('grayButton');
  jQuery('input:reset').removeClass('button');
  jQuery('input:reset').addClass('grayButton');
  jQuery('input:submit').attr('disabled', true);

 }

}
-->
</script>
```

as you have seen i'm trying to disable the submit buttons in the page while waiting the response .. but what is happen is the browser gives me a 404 error but with the same url i have... it's really strange cause it happen only when i trying to disable the submit not any other type...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem description is vague. If you do it this way, instead just *nothing* will happen. You shouldn't have got a 404, the page would just stick there where it is. Because if you disable the buttons immediately, the form cannot be submitted. Give the form the chance to submit. Set a timeout on the disable.

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    $('button').attr('disabled', true); 
}, 100); // Disable after 100 milliseconds.
```

That said and *unrelated* to your actual problem: do you know that you can just style the `disabled` buttons separately? You seem to add and remove classes all the time. That is unnecessary. Just give them all the same class `button` (or so) and use the `[disabled]` attribute-selector:

```
.button {
    /* Define here style of default button. */
}

.button[disabled] {
    /* Define here style of disabled button. */
}
```

Comment: thanks it's perfectly work sir thanks alot you notify me with the problem that i was almost there to find it ..:) for that thanks a lot